# Can I get my security token without having to reset it?

Tags: security, security-token, user-management

I need to get a user's security token but there are other things currently using it so I don't really want to reset it. Is there any way to retrieve this without having to reset it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" but I figured I'd ask - we could always use more questions.

Comment: In old Windoes system you could use a Password revealer tool, if the token is shown on some popup window, might worth a try

Comment: Just trying to understand - why do you need to reset the security token?       My understanding from your question - as other things(systems) using it - so you know the what is it. generally I miss it so I go for resetting it!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe not. I've never been able too short of finding the old email from when it was originally issued.

There is an active [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVuBUAV/allow-retrievable-security-token-through-sfdc-ui) on IdeaExchange. Please consider upvoting it.

Comment: That's right. Here's the idea: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrHFAA0

Comment: you can't get it because salesforce doesn't have it, it treats it just like a password, and so only stores a hash of it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a well designed system. It can be really tough to work with those restrictions and if you need to reset it, it affects everything connected to it. Although it's unlikely any time soon I'd like to see them redesign how security tokens work and are used.

Comment: The idea link for this has been upgraded to the new site. The new URL is https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVuBUAV/allow-retrievable-security-token-through-sfdc-ui

Answer (score 2):

When the user last changed his password, he should have gotten a reset token email.

Check your mail server for that user. It might store it there.

If you use a Google apps: check postini (Google's archive)

Email subject: `salesforce.com security token confirmation`

From: `support`

Text:

> Your Security Token Is Enclosed.
>
> Dear John,
>
> When accessing salesforce.com from outside of your company’s trusted
>   networks, you must add a security token to your password to log in to
>   a desktop client, such as Connect for Outlook, Connect Offline,
>   Connect for Office, Connect for Lotus Notes, or the Data Loader.
>
> New security tokens are automatically sent to you when your
>   salesforce.com password is changed or when you request to reset your
>   security token.
>
> Your new security token is below. Note that security tokens are case
>   sensitive.
>
> User Name: your@email.com Security Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score -1):

No, definitely the only way to do this is to reset the token (unless you can find the original email), there is no other option. The token is *per user account*, so resetting it will only reset it for that user and won't affect other parts of the system.

You'll also need to ensure that the user email address is set correctly. As soon as you reset the token, the new token will be emailed to that address.

Answer (score -7):

I add a custom field to the user profile page layout to store the tokens & one for password also.  Helpful for API users.

Copy/paste from email when you reset token.  Update them on user account as tokens are reset.

Comment: That doesn't seem very secure...or wise from a legal standpoint.