# I get an error logging into Apex Data Loader. "Please check your username and password"

Tags: apex, login-errors

I can not log in to Apex Data Loader. When I enter my credentials they do not work, and the message I get is "Error logging in to Salesforce. Please check your username and password".

What I have done:

- checked multiple times that I can log in directly to Salesforce.com with my username and password.
- tried different values for instance server URL: https://login.salesforce.com (which is what our login popup points to) and https://na10.salesforce.com (which is the URL we have once we're logged in)
- have someone else on a different environment download Apex, and use their credentials to log in, it also did not work. They can log on to Salesforce.com but not to Apex Data Loader.

We're using a non-profit license for Salesforce.com, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: have appended security token after your password ?

Comment: Prabhat, no, I have not. Can you point me to where I can learn how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You required to Use Salesforce token along with your password.

To obtain this token follow below steps

1)From your personal settings, enter Reset in the Quick Find box, then select Reset My Security Token.
  2)  Click Reset Security Token. The new security token is sent via email to the email address in your Salesforce personal settings.

ADD this token to end of your password in password column and you should be good to go.

Comment: Is there a way to get the security token without resetting it? - EDIT - nope you cannot as answered here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/810/can-i-get-my-security-token-without-having-to-reset-it